# NP-hard (3-)SAT variant with $n$ clauses and $f(n)$ variables

Tags: reductions, np-hard, 3-sat

With the purpose of proving my problem NP-hard, I'd like to reduce from a SAT variant (which of course should remain NP-hard) in which not two parameters are present (typically $n$ clauses and $m$ variables) but only one, so $n$ clauses and $f(n)$ variables, for some function $f$.

I've tried to look up 3-SAT (SAT with exactly 3 literals per clause) with exactly 3 occurrences of a variable, as this would imply I'd have $n$ clauses and $n$ variables which would be perfect. Alas, [this paper](http://cedric.cnam.fr/%7Ebentzc/INITREC/Files/CB11.pdf) proves 3-SAT with **at most** 3 occurrences per variable is trivial, including my specific case of exactly 3 occurrences.

All hope is not lost though, as in the same paper, it is proven that 3-SAT with at most $k$ occurrences per variable, with $k > 3$ is NP-hard. I'm looking into the details of the reduction to see if by chance they have proved the specific case of exactly $k$ occurrences per variable to be NP-hard (which would extend to the general case of at most $k$ occurrences per variable), but wanted to ask this question here while searching:

**Does there exist an NP-hard SAT variant with $n$ clauses and $f(n)$ variables?**

EDIT: the answer is yes, there exists such an NP-hard SAT variant, see [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19582/3-sat-problem-with-number-of-clauses-equal-to-number-of-variables), so I'd like to modify this question just for the sake of it:

**Does there exist an NP-hard 3-SAT variant with $n$ clauses and $f(n)$ variables?**

(As a reminder, In this post 3-SAT means exactly 3 literals per clause, as opposed to the more common meaning of at most 3 literals per clause, used in the solution for my first question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General 3-SAT is reducible to 3-SAT with $n$ clauses and $3n$ variables, as more variables would mean one isn't even present in some clause and can be removed, which can be done linearly.

Conversely it's also equivalent to 3-SAT with $m$ variables and $m(m+1)(m+1)/6$ clauses, as otherwise some clauses would be redundant, and again this can be checked in linear time.

Comment: I forgot another detail, occurrence! Your answer is of course correct *w.r.t.* the question I asked, so I will start a new post instead of modifying my question and cheating you out of the answer...