# Complexity of variant of 3-SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

This [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19582/157195) introduces a new variant of 3-SAT called EQUAL-3-SAT where the number of clause is same as number of variables, and it is shown to be NP-complete.

I want to ask if the monotone version of this EQUAL-3-SAT is also NP-complete ,by monotone ,I mean where each clause can either contain all positive or all negative literals.

We can reduce 3-SAT instance to monotone-3-SAT but I don't understand how to maintain the *"clause is equal to number of variables"* property when converting 3-SAT into monotone-3-SAT

> Motivation : The EQUAL-3-SAT is one of the most restrictive variant of
> 3-SAT I've seen yet ,with respect to the number of clauses it needs as
> an input ,thus I was wondering if this kind of restriction maintains
> its compleixty status when we try to make the variable overlappings
> between clauses less complex ,by adding the monotone condition ,we can
> make the overlappings less complex as every clauses is either all true
> or all false .

---

Does there exist a reduction from EQUAL-3-SAT to monotone-EQUAL-3-SAT ?

Comment: I noticed you've asked a fair number of questions of the form "is this variant of SAT NP-complete/#P-hard/...?"  It's possible you might be more likely to get answers if you provide some motivation in each post about why each particular variant is important and motivate its relevance.  Anyone can come up with a lot of variants, but I'm not sure whether it will be useful to others in the future to have a long list of questions asking about each possible variant one could imagine.

Comment: Sure. I will add my motivation behind my question from now on.

Comment: Try reducing monotone-3-SAT to monotone-EQUAL-3-SAT using the ideas given [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/19584/107966). It is easy.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami yeah ,we can reduce monotone-3-SAT to monotone-EQUAL-3-SAT using those methods ,Thanks for the advice.

Comment: But when using those methods there appears duplicate clauses isn't it

Comment: like If n>m, we introduce a fresh variable x that does not appear anywhere in ϕ and add to ϕ exactly n−m+1 clauses of the form (x) , isn't it just like adding duplicate clauses

Comment: Yes, there will be duplicates. If you want to avoid that you can add a new clause $(x \lor y )$ where $x$ is the new variable and $y$ is an existing variable. Since $n > m$, there exists sufficient number of such $y$'s.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Thanks ,But we can also make it all negatives right?

Comment: got it ,thank you for your repsonses ,I self-answer my question ,is that okay?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami But if we make it ,then won't it change the satsifiability status of the problem

Comment: @Anuj No. It won't change the satisfiability status. Please write the answer. It is encouraged!

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Oh okay ,then , when you mentioned that sign of clauses added doesn't matter ,I just thought ,shouldn't changing set of clauses also change the satisfiability of the original formula and just for calrity if we make it so that the clause we add are signed positively and the next one we add is negative ,then this changes the satisfiability satutus of the formula

Comment: Hi @Anuj. Please join [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146759/complexity-of-variant-of-3-sat) for discussion.